# NetCoreApp System.codedom

Tags: c#, nuget-package, .net-core

I'm creating a new .NET Core application and would like to use `System.CodeDom` (and .Compiler) as reference. I require the classes: `CSharpCodeProvider`, `CodeMemberProperty`, ... However i'm not finding a package via nuget where these types are available. Anybody who knows in which package I can find this for .NET core?

Comment: CodeDOM has been superseded by Roslyn. You learn the latter instead.

Comment: CodeDom is available on .NET Core. I'm using it.
Add ```<PackageReference Include="System.CodeDom" Version="5.0.0" />```.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one `CoreCompat.System.CodeDOM` which is resolving some of my issues. This is still in beta, so if there is an RTM available this can be added here.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDOM is not currently available on .Net Core and [it seems it's not planned to be included anytime soon](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9485).

Your best choice is to use Roslyn libraries instead.