# Porting code from .net 4.x to .net core. What replaces System.CodeDom?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to port some old code from .net 4.x to .net core. Specifically this:

```
var ctd = new CodeTypeDeclaration(name);
ctd.IsClass = true;

var space = new CodeNamespace(GeneratedNamespace);
space.Types.Add(ctd);

var unit = new CodeCompileUnit();
unit.Namespaces.Add(space);
```

I'm not too familiar with what this is actually doing, but I see it uses System.CodeDom, which doesn't seem to exist in .net core. I'm having a tough time searching for these specific examples though, and have no idea how to replace them. Is there some way to do this in .net core? Also, is there any documentation somewhere on what is missing in .net core when compared to earlier versions, and what the substitute are? I assume i'll run into more issues in the future, and would like some way to figure out how to deal with them.

Comment: A small portion of the `System.CodeDom` namespace is being [added in .NET Standard 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0.md) (and consequently implemented on .NET Core 2.0). You may check which APIs are already added using the .NET Standard github repository. I do not know any drop-in "replacement" for this namespace.

Comment: According to their GitHub statements an implementation of System.CodeDom is not planned for .NET Core or Standard. 
Following this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543882/netcoreapp-system-codedom), there's seems to be a 3rd party Nuget package as a replacement (still beta):
`Install-Package CoreCompat.System.CodeDOM -Pre`.
I copied the code and it seems to compile and run in .NET Core.